# MySQL Pivot table, get rows with max created_at date

Tags: mysql

I have a pivot table with the following structure:

```
property_id   user_id   role       created_at
1             23        Manager    2019-05-20 00:00:00
1             45        Resident   2018-03-12 00:00:00 
1             67        Manager    2020-05-19 00:00:00
```

In the above example, user 67 is the current Manager for the Property. User 23 was the prior Manager.

How do I extract all rows of current roles and users for each property?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And note that this is the most frequently asked question under this tag

Answer (score 1):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where property_id = t.property_id and role = t.role and created_at > t.created_at
)
```

Or with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where t.created_at = (
  select max(created_at) from tablename
  where property_id = t.property_id and role = t.role
)
```

For MySql 8.0+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select t.property_id, t.user_id, t.role, t.created_at
from  (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by property_id, role order by created_at desc) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.rn = 1
```